# How to get DataTable columns value in a TextBox on ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged Event?

Tags: datatable, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I have a combobox 'cbxProject' populated with Projects data using the following code:

```
 using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(PrjConn))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand comm1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT prj1.PROJ_REF, PTITLE FROM prj1 ORDER BY prj1.CONTRACTNO", connection);
            adapt.SelectCommand = comm1;
            adapt.Fill(tblProjects);
            //Bind Comboboxes
            //PROJ_REF Combobox
            cbxProject.ValueMember = "PROJ_REF";
            cbxProject.DisplayMember = "PROJ_REF";

            cbxProject.DataSource = tblProjects;
        }
```

On my C# form I have a textbox 'txtTitle' to get the Project Title 'PTITLE' whenever combobox 'cbxProject' SelectedIndexChanged like this:

```
 private void cbxProject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtTitle.Text = tblProjects.Rows[0]["PTITLE"].ToString();
    }
```

But I'm getting only the Rows[0] value in txtTitle.Text. every time SelectedIndex is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I have sorted this problem with the following edits:

```
private void cbxProject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int row = cbxProject.SelectedIndex;
        txtTitle.Text = comboDataSet.Tables["tblProjects"].Rows[row]["PTITLE"].ToString();


    }
```